# Keep active menu open on the new page of web site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a kind of drop down menu. But when I click some submenu link, the new page of my web site is opening, but the menu is closing. But on the new page of the web-site active menu must be open!

I tried to implement what I have in simple way on JSFiddle: [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/dmitry313/dfgjx22j/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="clickme">Click me 1</a>

        <ul style="display:none">
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <li> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="clickme">Click me 2</a>

            <ul style="display:none">
                <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

**AJAX:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#menu li > a').click(function (e) {

        if ($(this).next('ul').length > 0) {

            e.preventDefault();

            var subNav = $(this).next('ul');

            if (subNav.is(':visible')) {
                subNav.slideUp('normal')
                $(this).removeClass("selected");
            } else {
                $('#menu ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                subNav.slideDown('normal');
                $("a.selected").removeClass("selected");
                $(this).addClass("selected");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new page just remove the **style="display:none"** from the respective **ul** according to the page.. As it will be a new page, it won't effect the main page..

Comment: I had this idea, but I can't implement it with ajax. It is necessary to find active menu, and after that remove **style="display:none"** using the ajax code.

Comment: So, that's why I'm asking for the help